# Nested ng-template script not working as per requirement, alternate solution required

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have code similar to this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="maintemplate">
 DO SOMETHING HERE/SOME MORE DIV TAGS 
<script type="text/ng-template" id="zipCodeModal">
    <div custominclude = " 'zipCodelookup.html'"> </div>
</script>
<div id="zipCodeModal"></div>
</script>
<div ng-include="'maintemplate'"></div>
```

This doesnt work as i understand that script tag will look for end of first script tag `('</script>')` . I cannot use external file as it fails to load some of the data.

Is there any alternate solution for this

Comment: It is illegal to duplicate `id` attribute values. And as you have stated the browser will not parse nested `<script>` tags. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @georgeawg the inner scripts opens html files using custom directive . But the outer script is reusable but not a file (as it causes issues while rendering data from backend), the outer script ends abruptly when it sees the first </script> . Is there any way to overcome it.